# I could not understand this that why to use flush() method of a PrintWriter class?

Tags: java

Why the code here is using `flush()` method of the `PrintWriter` class after getting message from `messageBox` field....?

```
public void connectToSocket() {

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream);
        System.out.println("Connected Successfully");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {    
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class sendMessageListener implements ActionListener {    
    try {    
         writer.println(messageBox.getText());
         writer.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {    
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: To flush the buffer. Did you consider reading the Javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor for PrintWriter does not autoflushes its contents. This means that  it uses an internal buffer since writing operations are expensive.

If you want to write the buffer immediately to the stream, you just call the flush method.

If you had used the constructor for autoflush

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream,true);
```

you would not need to call the flush method, because it will flush the internal buffer as soon as a new line command (println() in this case) is called.